# Mysql query Key to speed calc with 10M rows

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql table with 10M rows, 3gb of data and 20Gb of available ram.
I have made a key with X, Y, ID, string1 and intnumber.

I have to make a search based on latitude and longitude and it takes around 50 seconds every time.

I need to get the ID, string1 , intnumber near the $querylatitude and $querylalongitude

```
$query = "SELECT ID, string1 , intnumber, X AS latitude , Y as longitude,   
    (6371 * ACOS( 
                SIN(RADIANS(X)) 
              * SIN(RADIANS(" . $querylatitude . ")) 
            + COS(RADIANS(Y - " . $querylalongitude . ")) 
            * COS(RADIANS(X)) 
            * COS(RADIANS(" . $querylatitude . "))
                )
             ) AS distance
            FROM pointsofinteres
            HAVING distance < 1000 
            ORDER BY distance ASC limit 1"
            ;
```

Thanks in advance.

Added Information:

```
CREATE TABLE `pointsofinteres` (
  `Y` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `X` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_spanish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `ID` bigint(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TIPO_VIAL` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `string1` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `intnumber` varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
  `EXTENSION` varchar(20) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_spanish_ci;


--
-- Indexes for table `edificios`
--
ALTER TABLE `edificios`
  ADD KEY `Índice 1` (`ID`,`string1`),
  ADD KEY `Índice 2` (`X`,`Y`,`ID`,`string1`,`intnumber`);
COMMIT;

/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET COLLATION_CONNECTION=@OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
```

Query 1

```
SELECT ID, string1 , intnumber, X AS latitude , Y as longitude, 
    (6371 * ACOS(
                SIN(RADIANS(X))
                * SIN(RADIANS(43.1454))
                + COS(RADIANS(Y - -2.60527))
                * COS(RADIANS(X))
                * COS(RADIANS(43.1454))
                )
    ) AS distance
    FROM pointsofinteres

    HAVING distance < 2000 /* 1 KM  a la redonda */
    ORDER BY distance ASC limit 1
```

Result: "48001" "ANDRA MARI"    "5" "43.1454591226404"  "-2.60528392721142" "0,006670513714780895"

/* Filas afectadas: 0  Filas encontradas: 1  Advertencias: 0  Duración para 1 consulta: 30,781 seg. */

Query 2

```
SELECT ID, string1 , intnumber 
    (6371 * ACOS(
                SIN(RADIANS(X))
                * SIN(RADIANS(43.1454))
                + COS(RADIANS(Y - -2.60527))
                * COS(RADIANS(X))
                * COS(RADIANS(43.1454))
                )
    ) AS distance
    FROM pointsofinteres

    HAVING distance < 2000 /* 1 KM  a la redonda */
    ORDER BY distance ASC limit 1
```

Result: "48001" "ANDRA MARI"    "5" "0,006670513714780895"

/* Filas afectadas: 0  Filas encontradas: 1  Advertencias: 0  Duración para 1 consulta: 30,625 seg. */

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Please share a reproducable example (containing the table structure, the indices, sample input and output data). If this is too much, you should at least post the execution plan of your query

Comment: you can speed up the query by storing directly in database `SIN(RADIANS(X))` and `COS(RADIANS(X))` so MySQL don't need to calculate them for every record

Comment: you say "I need to get the ID, string1 , intnumber" so why you extract also `X AS latitude , Y as longitude` in the `SELECT`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to find out all the locations that are located in the circle with the radius of the given distance and return the closest to the given location specified by $querylatitude/$querylalongitude. Right now it scans the whole table to calculate the distance to the given location.

What you can do is to calculate the possible MAX X, MIN X MAX Y, and MIN Y (when delat y/x is 0) based on the given distance and $querylatitude/$querylalongitude, then you can add that to the query condition to limit the scope to the locations in the circle:

X BETWEEN MIN_X and MAX_X and Y BETWEEN MIN_Y and MAX_Y

Since X/Y already indexed, it will be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks PeterHe, i have now fast and ready.

```
SELECT ID, string1 , intnumber 
    (6371 * ACOS(
                SIN(RADIANS(X))
                * SIN(RADIANS(43.1454))
                + COS(RADIANS(Y - -2.60527))
                * COS(RADIANS(X))
                * COS(RADIANS(43.1454))
                )
    ) AS distance
    FROM pointsofinteres

    WHERE X BETWEEN 42.1454 AND 44.1454 AND Y BETWEEN -3.60527 AND -1.60527
    ORDER BY distance ASC limit 1
```

/* Filas afectadas: 0  Filas encontradas: 1  Advertencias: 0  Duración para 1 consulta: 0,813 seg. */